# Сделать изменения и коммит после команды git chekout

Tags: git

Имеется ветка

```
A-B-C-D-E
```

Что произойдет если я перейду командой `checkout B`, на более ранний коммит, сделаю изменения в файлах и сделаю коммит

```
git add -A
git commit -m "Message"
```

Comment: Вы наверняка уже попробовали. Что произошло?

Comment: Остался только коммит А-В, но можно ли так делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

«ветка» в программе *git* — это всего лишь (плавающий) указатель на коммит.

после команды `checkout хэш-коммита` этот указатель так и продолжит указывать на коммит `e`.

и вы в любой момент можете вернуться «обратно» командой `checkout имя-ветки`.

---

а созданный вами коммит, если вы не пометили его каким-либо из указателей — меткой (*tag*) или веткой — исчезнет после очередной сборки мусора.